# Block 'Save Address' pop up using automation in python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-3.11

While performing selenium automation using python, a pop up appears to save the address. How can I block the pop up in python?
[Save Address pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9qMA.png)

I tried using the following code.

```
``options = ChromeOptions()
`options.add_argument("test-type")`
`options.add_argument("disable-notifications")`
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
driver = get_webdriver_for("chrome",
                           desired_capabilities=capabilities,
                           options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")`
time.sleep(2)`
```

The pop up appears once I click the submit button after filling a form.`your text`

Answer (score 0):

Right-click > Inspect

Work out the css selector

Scroll up the html to see if there is an iframe (if there is, switch to it first)

Send the click

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply . I tried checking the html code but there is no iframe. What else could be done to block the pop-up using python.

Comment: If the popup always displays, just wait for and click the 'No thanks' button